# Windows 10 audio configuration keeps changing from 7.1 to stereo at random

Tags: audio

I don't use HDMI or DP for audio. I have been searching for an answer on this issue for a long time but I can't find any help through google, Microsoft, realtek, my motherboard manufacturer, or any forums. I have tried multiple drivers and a few programs that can be used to mix audio but windows 10 keeps randomly changing my default playback devices setting from 7.1 to stereo. I say randomly because I don't have to shut off or restart my pc or powered speakers for this to happen. It works great for a while until it changes and then I have to go select 7.1 audio again and again. I've read a lot of help forums on this issue but everybody else was using HDMI and they say they fixed it by cutting the wire in their HDMI cable for pin 19 but since I'm not using HDMI I believe I am having a different issue. I love the way it sounds in 7.1 so I would love any help anybody can offer! Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what make/model of speakers you are using? I would assume, if you are using 7.1 surround settings that you have 7 speakers in your set plus a subwoofer, and you are using 4 audio cables plugged in to your computer from your speakers?

Comment: Sorry I should have included that info. I'm using three different 2.1 speakers. Klipsch 2.1 pro audio. so I only have 6 actual surround speakers but it sounds amazing with speaker fill and channel phantoming applied until it reverts to stereo and not only does it revert to stereo it changes the default format back to 16 bit 192000 Hz from the 24 bit 192000 Hz that I set it at. They are plugged into 3 different audio jacks on my motherboard with the center channel being simulated. It all works great until it changes from what I have it set at to it's default.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with hardware polling? If so how do I get windows 10 to stop changing my settings?